# Searching for element on a page with a particular class

Tags: node.js, playwright

I'm using Playwright with Node.js.

I am looking at a page with a table.

Each of the cells () has either the class="day unavailable" or class="day available"

I am trying to test if there are **any** cells with "day available". I don't need to know which one, just if any exist.

I am using this code:

checkDates = await page.$('.datechoice > .condensed > tbody > tr > .available')

Which I was hoping would evaluate to true if there was a cell with that class on the page.

However it evaluates to false every time, even if one of the cells has the class "day available"

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show the html? Also, have you tried some simpler selector like page.$('td.available').

Answer (score 0):

You can you use `page.$$(selector)` (double `$$`) to get all your matching elements.

This is from [the docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page/#page-query-selector-all):

> The method finds all elements matching the specified selector within the page. If no elements match the selector, the return value resolves to [].

You will probably want to simplify your selector as well. Good practice is [not imbed implementation logic in selectors](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#avoid-selectors-tied-to-implementation).

try something like:

```
const result = await page.$$('[class="day available"]')
```